# Explain how the following query works?

Tags: mysql, join, aggregate-functions

I have a mysql query which works in a strange way. I am posting the 2 queries with input data changed and the output are listed under each query.

Query 1 (Area to be noted `BETWEEN '13/05/11' AND '30/05/11'`):

```
SELECT COUNT(pos_transaction_id) AS total,
DATE_FORMAT(pt.timestamp,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%S') AS Date,
SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM pos_transactions pt 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(pt.timestamp,'%e/%m/%y') BETWEEN '13/05/11' AND '30/05/11'
GROUP BY WEEK(pt.timestamp) ORDER BY pt.timestamp
```

Output:
[image]

Query 2 (Area to be noted `BETWEEN '3/05/11' AND '30/05/11'`):

```
SELECT COUNT(pos_transaction_id) AS total,
DATE_FORMAT(pt.timestamp,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%S') AS Date,
SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM pos_transactions pt 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(pt.timestamp,'%e/%m/%y') BETWEEN '3/05/11' AND '30/05/11'
GROUP BY WEEK(pt.timestamp) ORDER BY pt.timestamp
```

Output:
[image] 
Now when the range is increased in the second query why am I getting just one record ? And even in the first query I am getting records which is out of range. What is wrong with it??

EDIT

The changed query looks like this and still not doing what I wanted it to do.

```
SELECT COUNT(pos_transaction_id) AS total,
DATE_FORMAT(pt.timestamp,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%S') AS Date,
SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM pos_transactions pt
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(pt.timestamp,'%e/%m/%y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/05/11','%e/%m/%y') AND STR_TO_DATE('30/05/11','%e/%m/%y')
GROUP BY WEEK(pt.timestamp) ORDER BY pt.timestamp
```

The output is:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're seeing the result of the intersection of two bad practices.

First, the date_format() function returns a string. Your WHERE clause does a string comparison. In PostgreSQL

```
select '26/04/2011' between '13/05/11' AND '30/05/11';
--
T
```

That's because the string '26' is between the strings '13' and '30'. If you write them as dates, though, PostgreSQL will correctly tell you that '2011-04-26' (following the datestyle setting on my server) isn't in that range.

Second, I'm guessing that the odd out-of-range values appear because you're using an indeterminate expression in your aggregate. The expression `WEEK(pt.timestamp)` doesn't appear in the SELECT list. I think every other SQL engine on the market will throw an error if you try to do that. Since it's not in the SELECT list, MySQL will return an apparently random value from that aggregate range.

To avoid these kinds of errors, don't do string comparisons on date or timestamp ranges, and don't use indeterminate aggregate expressions.

Posting DDL and minimal SQL INSERT statements to reproduce the problem helps people help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm absolutely not sure, but it is maybe the comparison is done as a `string` and not as a date.

`DATE_FORMAT` returns a `string` and both your condition are strings too.

You should try without the `DATE_FORMAT`, just the column, or maybe trying to convert the condition to a date.

I'm thinking something like this :

```
pt.timestamp BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('13/05/11', '%e/%m/%y') AND STR_TO_DATE('30/05/11', '%e/%m/%y')
```

Comment: check my edit i still have problem with that.. Do you need anything else to see ??

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you are meaning to do

```
WHERE pt.timestamp BETWEEN TO_DATE('13/04/11', 'dd/mm/yy') AND TO_DATE('30/05/11', 'dd/mm/yy')
```

Before you are asking it for a string between two other strings.

**Update**

I think a few point is being missed here. Based on the calculations you are doing on `pos_transactions.timestamp` I am going to assume it's a type of `timestamp`. In your query you need to use the timestamp directly if you want to do a range compare. A timestamp already contains all the data you need to do this comparison. You don't need to covert it to Day/Month/Year to compare it.

What you need to do is this:

Find all values where my `timestamp` is between `create a new date from '13/05/11'` AND `create a new date from '30/05/11'`. `pt.timestamp` is already a timestamp, no need to convert it in your WHERE clause.

What you keep doing is converting it into a String representation. Thats ok when you want to display it, but not when you want to compare it with other values.

Comment: dont i have to apply DATE_FORMAT() to timestamp ??

Comment: the `TO_DATE` function don't exist in MySQL, but there's a `STR_TO_DATE` one : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date @Deepak `DATE_FORMAT` returns a string, I think this is the problem, see my answer.

Comment: You are still using DATE_FORMAT on the pt.timestamp, just use pt.timestamp by itself in the WHERE clause.